# Change line Separator color using iText7

Tags: itext7

I want to change the line Separator using iText7 but did not know how to use `line.setColor(Color.RED);` from the example here.

```
SolidLine line = new SolidLine(1f);
line.setColor(Color.RED);
LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator(line);
```

Comment: You could implement the ILineDrawer interface to draw any kind of line, but iText ships
with three implementations that are ready to use: SolidLine, DottedLine, and DashedLine. Each of these classes allows you to change the line width and color. The DottedLine class also allows you to change the gap between the dots.

Refer example : https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-create-a-custom-dashed-line-separator

Comment: Hello S_G my problem is to change color of `SolidLine`

Comment: You never mentioned anything related to color change in your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code using which one should be able to set any color on SolidLine.

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new
PdfWriter("src/main/resources/test/output.pdf"));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
SolidLine line = new SolidLine(1f);
line.setColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator(line);
ls.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(50));
ls.setMarginTop(5);
document.add(ls);
document.add(new Paragraph(" test document pdf..."));
document.close();
```